# Сохранить несколько изображений в MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql, файлы

Есть обычная форма добавления фотографий на сервер:

```
<form method="post" multipart="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="img[]" multiple>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP обработка формы:

```
$img = $_FILES['img'];

if(!empty($img))
{
    $img_desc = reArrayFiles($img);
    print_r($img_desc);

    foreach($img_desc as $val)
    {
        $newname = date('YmdHis',time()).mt_rand().'.jpg';
        move_uploaded_file($val['tmp_name'],'./filedat/'.$newname);
    }
}

function reArrayFiles($file)
{
    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file['name']);
    $file_key = array_keys($file);

    for($i=0;$i<$file_count;$i++)
    {
        foreach($file_key as $val)
        {
            $file_ary[$i][$val] = $file[$val][$i];
        }
    }
    return $file_ary;
}
```

Данный код работает так, как мне нужно. Загружает несколько изображений на сервер. Но мне нужно еще к этому сделать так, чтобы ссылки на эти файлы сохранились в базу данных, чтобы потом их вывести на странице объявления.
Покажите, пожалуйста, пример кодом, как можно сохранить загружаемые картинки в Mysql в одну ячейку таким образом:

img1, img2, img3 и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы занести все ссылки в одну ячейку, Вам необходимо вот в этой части Вашего кода ввести переменную (например, $links), которая все эти ссылки будет содержать через запятую:

```
foreach($img_desc as $val)
{
    $newname = date('YmdHis',time()).mt_rand().'.jpg';
    move_uploaded_file($val['tmp_name'],'./filedat/'.$newname);
    $links .= './filedat/'.$newname.', ';

}
```

Ссылки, понятное дело, можно указать без папки filedat или, наоборот, полные - на Ваше усмотрение. Ну и потом создаёте таблицу в базе, куда данные будут заноситься, подключаетесь к базе и инсертом заносите данные. Как-нибудь так, например:

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'mydb');
$query = "INSERT INTO pics (links) VALUES ('$links')";
if($links) {
  mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}
```

Comment: Человеческое спасибо! Благодарю!

Answer (score 3):

Обычно, если вам необходимо привязать к какой либо записи в БД произвольное количество каких либо объектов, будь то ссылки на файлы, список параметров, набор ролей пользователя или еще что-то, то для этих сущностей используют отдельную таблицу с привязкой по ключу к основной.

```
CREATE TABLE main (
    id VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    .....,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE pictures(
    id INT,
    parent_id VARCHAR(20),
    path VARCHAR(500),
    INDEX parent (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES main(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: В качестве дополнения отмечу, что изображения желательно хранить не в БД, а на диске, а в БД записывать только ссылки/информацию о них.

Comment: Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: @Miron, правильное мнение!